# How do I use oncopy in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I try the following:

```
<div oncopy="myfunc('{{angularvar}}')">Copy me</div>
```

Then I get the error message:

> Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please
>   use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead.

However, there is no ng-copy. Any idea how I use oncopy in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to create your own directive where you can access the html element and bind to any event. Here a good tutorial http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

And the official doc http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: If you make your own "copy" directive, you can pass in angulars {{}} values.

Comment: Thanks. I also got a commit added to AngularJS so that this will be supported out of the box in future versions. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/147c6929a264a7b077a5f2cfc5aa9a0b9513acd7